# Connection to remote mysql server through ssh using python mysqldb connector passwordless

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, paramiko, auth-socket

**Python 3.8**

**Mysql  8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))**

Hi,

I want to connect to a distant mysql server using python's mysqldb connector and paramiko's sshtunnelforwarder.

I can connect to the database remotely without any problems by executing the following:

**Connecting to database using mysql password authentication**

```
server = new_ssh_server(config)
with server:
   print('Connection', server.local_bind_address)
   cnx = MySQLdb.connect(host = '127.0.0.1',
   port = server.local_bind_port,
   user = config['user'],
   passwd = config['password'],
   db = config['db'])
```

Queries work, I can read/write to database, no problem.

**I would like to connect to database without supplying mysql password, by using mysql auth_socket authentication method, through ssh.**

My attempts at this can be resumed by the following code:

**Connecting to database using mysql auth_socket authentication**

```
with server as tunnel:
    print('Tunnel:', tunnel.local_bind_address)
    cnx = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'hillbilly', password = '', db='tutut')#, unix_socket="/tmp/mysql.sock")
    res = pd.read_sql('select * from users;', cnx)
    print(res)
```

Which throws the following error:

```
File "connect_ssh_mysql_auth_socket.py", line 12, in <module>
    cnx = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'hillbilly', password = '', db='rsotest2')#, unix_socket="/tmp/mysql.sock")
  File "...../lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...../lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")
```

I have and existing mysql**d**.sock on the distant server that I symlinked to **/tmp/mysql.sock**, but the error remains. I have also added the next line to **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf**:

```
socket=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

But I still get the same error when trying to connect remotely.

Specifying the **unix_socket='/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'** to mysqldb connector (commented in **Connecting to database using mysql auth_socket authentication**) does not fix the issue.

I seem to misunderstand the use of mysql.sock, mysqld.sock.
I was not able to find nor create a mysql.sock socket.
Is what I am trying to do possible? I remember reading somewhere that unix sockets only work locally, does this mean it is not achievable?

Any help/explanation would be appreciated.

**(EDIT AND CLOSING)**
So this is not possible. Following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147040/log-in-into-mysql-account-with-unix-socket), auth_socket needs local access to the socket file (usually /tmp/mysql.sock) to run autentication tests, so not accessible through ssh tunneling.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication to remote mysql server using auth_socket plugin is not possible through sshtunnel, as the plugin requires local access to the socket file. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147040/log-in-into-mysql-account-with-unix-socket) for more information.